# Does the redirect_canonical filter matter in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

It is a story when you want to always add a slash at the end of a fixed page of Wordpress.
First, it seems that someone in the project added the following:

> wp-content/themes/demo/functions.php

```
function add_trailing_slash($uri, $type) {
    if ($type != 'single') {
        $uri = trailingslashit($uri);
    }
    return $uri;
}
add_filter('user_trailingslashit', 'add_trailing_slash', 10, 2);
```

However, unfortunately, I was able to access without a slash with this alone.

**current situation**
`access > https://www.example.com/articles/art1`

**I would like to get redirected.**
`access > https://www.example.com/articles/art1 > redirect > https://www.example.com/articles/art1/`

Is it the influence of various plug-ins, since there is no project change history, I'm not sure if it's due to some customization.

I followed the source and came up with "redirect_canonical".
At the end of the method there was a filter like this:

> wp-includes/canonical.php

```
/**
    * Filters the canonical redirect URL.
    *
    * Returning false to this filter will cancel the redirect.
    *
    * @since 2.3.0
    *
    * @param string $redirect_url  The redirect URL.
    * @param string $requested_url The requested URL.
    */
$redirect_url = apply_filters( 'redirect_canonical', $redirect_url, $requested_url );
```

The variable(`$redirect_url`) before the filter has a slash.(https://www.example.com/articles/art1/)
The filtered variable(`$redirect_url`) has no slashes.(https://www.example.com/articles/art1)

The `$redirect_url` passed to "redirect_canonical" below was already "https://www.example.com/articles/art1" without the slash.

> wp-content/plugins/redirection/modules/wordpress.php

```
public function redirect_canonical( $redirect_url, $requested_url ) {
    if ( $this->matched ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $redirect_url;
}
```

**- summary -**

If there is no trailing slash, I want to redirect to a URL with a slash.
If you stop (comment out) `$redirect_url = apply_filters ( 'redirect_canonical', $redirect_url, $requested_url );` in the "redirect_canonical" function of "wp-includes/canonical.php", **it will behave as expected**.
However, I'm not familiar with Wordpress, so I'm trying to avoid (comment out) this part and investigate if it's a good one.

**- adding -**

> with filter (current situation)

`$redirect_url = apply_filters ( 'redirect_canonical', $redirect_url, $requested_url );` (wp-includes/canonical.php::around line 789)

access to `https://www.example.com/articles/art1`

```
Request URL: https://www.example.com/articles/art1
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200
Remote Address: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

> without filter (comment out)

`// $redirect_url = apply_filters ( 'redirect_canonical', $redirect_url, $requested_url );` (wp-includes/canonical.php::around line 789)

access to `https://www.example.com/articles/art1`

```
Request URL: Request URL: https://www.example.com/articles/art1
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 301
Remote Address: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Request URL: Request URL: https://www.example.com/articles/art1/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200
Remote Address: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

If I remove the filter it redirects and works as expected.
Is there any problem if I remove the filter?

Comment: What do you see in the Network tab of your browser devtools when you try these URLs with and without trailing slashes? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @O.Jones Added description. If I remove the filter it redirects. So I would like to remove the filtering.